# dynamic URL rewriting .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost

I'm new to URlRewriting and I've been having some problems rewriting my URLs, I have one single .php index page in which the content is filled using php depending on the url variables.

My problem is that I cannot seem to find the correct expressions to get it working.
For my homepage I'm only sending out 1 variable like

```
"index.php?page=home"
```

BUT for other pages I'm using up to 4 variables like "index.php?page=about&content=about-news&id=27&pn=1"

Now I got as far as getting 1 or 2 working seperately but not together using:

```
RewriteRule ^((.*)+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&content=$2
```

I've been looking around on google and Stackoverflow for the past few days but I cannot seem to find a working solution, does anyone have any ideas of how to get this working? 
Cheers

Comment: I don't think that you have really looked on google. This is a really common problem. And there are some sites that describe how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You can then look at the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable to see what was asked for.

That should work for you, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is one rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

then in your index.php file your split the route into piecies:

```
$route = (!isset($_GET['route']))?'':$_GET['route']);
$parts = explode('/', $route);

So your old urls like this:
index.php?page=home 
index.php?page=about&content=about-news&id=27&pn=1
index.php?page=$1
index.php?page=$1&content=$2

Become:
Example: `http://example.com/controller/action/do/value`
or       `http://example.com/$parts[0]/$parts[1]/$parts[2]/$parts[3]/$parts[4]`
```

Keeping to the idea of controller->action->do->value its easy to assign routes.

`?page=` will be your **controller**

`?content=` will be your **action**

`?id=` will be your **subaction | do | value** ect

Comment: My hero, wasn't working so I've been messing around with my code, seems I had put a =! instead of !=, in turn returning "1" instead of my variables; working as intended now, thanks!